# How to play 2nd svg when 1st is finished? (scroll animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I have a slight problem with an svg scroll animation.

I have this scroll animation here:

```
var path = document.querySelectorAll('path'), 
    percentScroll; //had to add the code as you know but it's better if you just take a look at the JSFiddle//
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bayron2304/f6be8rt4/ .
The problem is that the animations start at the same time while scrolling and I want the 2nd one to start as soon as the 1st one ends (Take a look at the JSFiddle if you don't know what I'm talking about).